# How to populate HTML 5 input[date] field with another input[date] value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After banging my head on a wall for a day, and reading a lot of answers online, I finally came out with a simple way to insert a date value into a date input control.

Below is the solution. Guess it might help others too

```
<input type="date" class="form-control arial no-radius" id="StartDate" onchange="dataClerk('set expiry date')"/>
```

```js
function dataClerk(action) {
  if (action == 'set expiry date') {
    var date = new Date($('#StartDate').val());

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    if (month < 10) {
      month = '0' + month;
    }

    if (day < 10) {
      day = '0' + day;
    }

    var show = (year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
    $('#EndDate').val(show);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="form-control arial no-radius" id="StartDate" onchange="dataClerk('set expiry date')" />

<input type="date" class="form-control arial no-radius" id="EndDate" disabled/>
```

```
function dataClerk(action) {
   if (action == 'set expiry date') {
      var date = new Date($('#StartDate').val());
      var day = date.getDate();
      var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
      var year = date.getFullYear();
         if (month < 10) {
           month = '0' + month;
         }
         if (day < 10) {
           day = '0' + day;
         }
         var show = (year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
         $('#EndDate').val(show);
   }
}
```